# Get variable python in TCL

Tags: python-3.x, tcl

I have this code in python (myscript.py) :

```
import os
oname2 = "Mark"
onamelen = str(len(oname2))
print(oname2)
print(onamelen)
```

Right now , i have this code in tcl :

```
set output "python C:/myscript.py"
set fp [open |$output r]

set v {}
while { [gets $fp data] > -1 } {
lappend v $data 
}

puts $v
close $fp
```

To reach my variable i must to make a `print` in my python code.I would like to get the variable `onamelen` and `oname2` in my script tcl.Maybe there is one package to integrate a code python into my code tcl ? Or another solution than to open a pipe .

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you _have_ to call the python script the way you're calling it, or can you use `exec` instead?

Comment: exec is a another solution , you are right , but i would like to do without pipe command or exec, just get my 2 variables without a print command in my script python

Comment: Where will the definitive contents of the variable reside?

Comment: My variables will be in a list

Comment: What is the purpose to do such a thing? Why you don't write the data you need on a file, and then you read from tcl.

Comment: simply , i don't want read my file 2 times, i have python which reads a text file and it puts me in variables.